# Using If Statement in Excel to populate when typing in a cell

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to find out if I can make a formula where I type in any value in a cell and then the next cell autopopulates with the city.  Basically it will just be an address field for customers and the city will always remain the same.  I just want it to be able to be blank if there is no data in the cell before it and if there is something typed in there it will populate the city in the next cell and the state in the next.

Comment: You will want to utilize the SheetChange method int he workbook object.  Then use the offset method on the target in that method to provide a value to the next cell. -  Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

=if("a1"="","","city name") This is an if statement that is checking if the designated cell is blank and if it is then it will show blank, if there is something in there, then it will populate with what you have in "city name"

Answer (score 0):

With “a cell” being in ColumnA (staring in A2), your city in B1 and State in C1 (they may already be labels) then:

```
=IF($A2="","",IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),$B$1,$C$1))
```

copied across one column and down may suit. If the resulting sequence is the wrong way round then either change EVEN to ODD or switch the contents of B1 and C1.